# Add GET parameters to q.io.xhr

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

In jQuery i can append GET parameters by specifying argument `data`:

```
// sends request to http://example.com?foo=bar&hello=world
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    method: 'get',
    data: {foo: 'bar', hello: 'world'}
})
```

However I can't see such option in [qooxdoo documentation](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.0.1/pages/communication/request_io.html). Of course I can encode parameters into url manually, but I can't believe that such a large javascript framework can't do this.

Maybe I am wrong and qooxdoo API accepts GET parameters in some way?

Comment: `req.setRequestData({foo: 'bar', hello: 'world'});` ?

Comment: @werehuman setRequestData is not available on q.io.xhr. Read the documentation: http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.2/website-api/#Xhr

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported as we wanted to keep the XHR implementation very close to the spec [1], as you can see in the API docs [2]. But this might be a good feature to be added in the future!

- [1] http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/
- [2] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/website-api/index.html#Xhr

Comment: Then why does the documentation state an optional 'data' parameter for the q.io.xhr.send function? That is horribly misleading and probably results in wasting precious time figuring out why the data isn't being passed. Please fix your docs: http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.2/website-api/#Xhr

Comment: The data is used for POST and therefore is necessary.